# Is there a hidden preference to get Mission Control to show application icons when grouping is turned off?

Tags: macos, mission-control, defaults

When I turn on grouping in Mission Control to I get the application icon overlaid on the windows that belong to the application. Is there a hidden option to show icons on ungrouped windows?

Answer (score 10):

Apple Icon>System Preferences>Mission Control>Unselect "Group windows by applications"

I think it is gonna work.

Edit: I tried, it works.

Comment: Welcome to [Apple.SE]! Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. I want to know if I can enable icons to show on **ungrouped windows**.

Comment: Worked for me when I _selected_ that option, instead of unselecting it.